# bat file for deleting index in solr

Tags: windows, curl, command-line, solr

I want to use a bat file to clear my index in solr. I found the following solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console

I downloaded cURL and a copied to my system32 folder. then I openend my windows commandline and typed 
`curl www.google.com` 
and it seems to work fine.

then I tried to add the following command:

```
curl http://berserkerpc:444/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

here the how to from solr:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_delete_all_documents_from_my_index.3F

I got the message back that there is a a syntactic issue with '<' while processing.

here is the complete bat file I want to create:

```
curl http://berserkerpc:444/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'  
curl http://berserkerpc:444/solr/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

any suggestion how to solve this???

Answer (score 1):

With Curl try calling -

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Be sure to use commit=true to reflect these changes.

OR Directly from from Browser -

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. I know the browser function, but I want to have a file to execute it several times :-(